# how to send multiple values to store in database by using socket and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sockets

I'm using this code and it's working fine with parameter value to store in database, but i want to store 2 more values in database how i can pass multiple values in database by using socket..
here is code...

```
    io.on('connection',function(socket){  
    console.log("A user is connected");
    socket.on('status added',function(status){
      add_status(status,function(res){

        if(res){
            io.emit('refresh feed',status);
        } else {
            io.emit('error');
        }
      });
    });
});

var add_status = function (status,callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        if (err) {
          callback(false);
          return;
        }
    connection.query("INSERT INTO `status` (`s_text`) VALUES ('"+status+"')",function(err,rows){
            connection.release();
            if(!err) {
              callback(true);
            }
        });
     connection.on('error', function(err) {
              callback(false);
              return;
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to read the documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

In your case, it would look like that:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("A user is connected");
    socket.on('status', function (statusObject) {
        add_status(statusObject, function (res) {

            if (res) {
                io.emit('refresh feed', statusObject.stat);
            } else {
                io.emit('error');
            }
        });
    });
});

var add_status = function (statusObject, callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            callback(false);
            return;
        }
        connection.query("INSERT INTO `status` (`s_status`, `s_id`, `s_comment`) VALUES ('"
            + statusObject.stat + "', '" + statusObject.id + "', '" + statusObject.comment
            + "')", function (err, rows) {
            connection.release();
            if (!err) {
                callback(true);
            }
        });
        connection.on('error', function (err) {
            callback(false);
            return;
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $("#add_status").click(function () {
        socket.emit('status', {
            stat: $("#status").val(),
            id: $("#id").val(),
            comment: $("#comment").val()
        });
    });
    socket.on('refresh feed', function (msg) {
        $("#show_comments").append(msg + '<br /><br />');
    });
});
```

Comment: database code is not a problem problem is that how to get values to that function from form..   io.on('connection',function(socket){  
    console.log("A user is connected");
    socket.on('status added',function(status){
      add_status(status,function(res){

        if(res){
            io.emit('refresh feed',status);
        } else {
            io.emit('error');
        }
      });
    });
});

var add_status = function (status,callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        if (err) {
          callback(false);
          return;
        }

Comment: OK, I will add your emits to the snippet.

Comment: Have you tried my last approach that passes a nested object?

Comment: Can you amplify why it is still not working? I can not run the code without a complete example, so I have to guess where the problem is.

Comment: iiqbal155 [at] g mail dot com email me on this email i'll send you complete code

Comment: I tried your app. It seems that 'status' is a predefined field name. I fixed this by using 'stat' instead of 'status'. Afterwards, the code worked for me: { stat: 'sfsda', id: '1' }